# When is the topos of algebras well-pointed?

Tags: reference-request, ct.category-theory, topos-theory

The monad version of the theorem at [Topos of coalgebras over a comonad](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/topos+of+coalgebras+over+a+comonad#related_concepts) is as follows:

Let $\mathcal{E}$ be an (elementary) topos. Then if a monad $T : \mathcal{E} \rightarrow \mathcal{E}$ has a right adjoint, then the category of algebras $T Alg(\mathcal{E})$ is itself an (elementary) topos.

Now I wonder about the well-pointedness of this topos of algebras, as it would have consequences for the identification of internal and external properties of $T Alg(\mathcal{E})$.

Are there any known theorems, that discuss when is this topos of algebras well-pointed?

Comment: Some comments: An example where it doesn't work is when $T(X) = X \times G$ with $G$ a non-trivial group object, and a condition under which it works is $T(1)=1$.

Comment: (for the case $T1=1$ I was assuming the base topos is well pointed of course)

Comment: When T has a right adjoint, isn't the category of algebras equivalent to the category of coalgebras on the left adjoint? So this is really about when toposes of coalgebras are well pointed?

Comment: Or is the question about T algebras in general regardless of whether they form a topos?

Comment: I think it can be approached via the topoi of coalgebras. I am not sure, whether the monad case also implies the comonad case, I feel like it should follow via duals but I have not checked, while the comonad case would automatically imply the monad case according to the nlab linked.

Comment: In other words instead of T having a right adjoint, T would only be right exact.

Comment: If $\mathcal E$ is sets, I was at some point pretty convinced that the only options for $T$ are the free $M$-set monads for $M$ a monoid, which are never well-pointed if $M$ is nontrivial.

Comment: @KevinArlin There are other examples, such as the Jónsson-Tarski topos (this example is from Johnstone's "When is a variety a topos?").

Comment: Ah wait, this is a category of algebras for a monad $T$ that probably does not have a right adjoint.

Comment: @JensHemelaer Ah, thanks, that's exactly the paper I didn't quite find whenever I was wondering about this. Indeed, Johnstone points out in that paper that if the forgetful functor on $T$-Alg is cocontinuous and $T$-Alg is a topos then $T$-Alg is $M$-Set for some $M$; if the Jónsson-Tarski sheafification monad were cocontinuous then so would be its forgetful functor.